# Push Notifications Are Not working When I disconnect my device from Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, swift4

I am Developing an IOS App using swift language. I have added Firebase based push notifications to my project. they works correctly when my device is attached to xcode or when i debug my app on my device. But when ever i disconnect my device from xcode or i use app without debugging push notification doesn't work. I am looking for a solution

My code in App Delegate File

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions,
                                                                completionHandler: { (bool, err) in

        })

    } else {

        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

in didregisterdevicewithtoken function

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

    }
    let tokenT = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    print(tokenT)
    guard let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() else {return}
    AppDelegate.DEVICEID = token
    print(token)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "token")

    connectToFCM()


}
```

And to generate notification

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    if let msg = userInfo["desc"] as? String
    {
        let title = userInfo["noti_title"] as? String
        createNotification(message: msg, title: title ?? "" )

    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}


func createNotification(message: String, title: String) {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title =  title
    content.body = message


    let triger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 2, repeats: false )
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "TextMessage", content: content, trigger: triger)



    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

```
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification,                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert,.badge,.sound])
}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let application = UIApplication.shared

    if(application.applicationState == .active){
        print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in foreground")

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        //        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NotificationViewController())


    }

    if(application.applicationState == .inactive)
    {
        print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in background")
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        //        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NotificationViewController())

    }

    /* Change root view controller to a specific viewcontroller */
    // let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    // let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerStoryboardID") as? ViewController
    // self.window?.rootViewController = vc

    completionHandler()
}

func connectToFCM()
{
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}
func initializeNotificationServices() -> Void {
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    // This is an asynchronous method to retrieve a Device Token
    // Callbacks are in AppDelegate.swift
    // Success = didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
    // Fail = didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Comment: Show some code for better understanding your question.

Comment: You have not implemented UNUserNotificationcenterdelegate method so you won’t receive push notifications. Refer this blog for complete information  https://medium.com/developerfly/firebase-push-notification-swift-tutorial-3e669dabbcca

Comment: Sorry i forgot to show you that i have updated my question again please check

Comment: Add that code also into question.

Comment: Have you put this code into FIRApp.configure()?? If it’s then your code completely right. Then problem is somewhere else.

Comment: yes i have put this code into FIRApp.configure(). And i have Found solution and my Push notifications are working Correctly now. I haden't added production apn certificate to my firebase after adding production apn certificate to firebase console i am getting notifications now.

Comment: thanks for the response. I am Pleased Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Now i have added production Apn certificate in firebase console and removed development apn certificate from firebase console. for those who had same issue please generate ur production apn from apple.developers and change your project scheme from debug to release in build tab.