# FCM push for iOS callback not called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with FCM push notifications.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void)
```

and

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void)
```

are not called when I receive a push. The notification is generated in my iPhone.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

is called instead but I don't understand why because it's deprecated.

The content of my notification:

```
{
  "to": "FCM Token",
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "notification": {
    "sound": "default",
    "title": "Test",
    "body": "Test",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  "data": {
    "id": 123456,
    "status": "11",
  }
}
```

In my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import Fabric
import Crashlytics
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import FBSDKLoginKit
import GoogleSignIn
import NotificationBannerSwift
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true


        return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        pprint(" - applicationWillResignActive - ")
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
        AppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        pprint(" - applicationDidEnterBackground - ")
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
         pprint(" - applicationWillEnterForeground - ")
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        pprint(" - applicationDidBecomeActive - ")
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        pprint(" - applicationWillTerminate - ")
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    private func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        pprint("apns token: ", deviceToken)
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
         Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.

        print(" ")
        print("-- New message classique --")
        print("Notification received : \(userInfo)")
        print(" ")

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(.noData)
    }

 // MARK: - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate methods
 extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

     // FOREGROUND: The method will be called on the delegate only if the application is in the foreground. If the method is not implemented or the handler is not called in a timely manner then the notification will not be presented. The application can choose to have the notification presented as a sound, badge, alert and/or in the notification list. This decision should be based on whether the information in the notification is otherwise visible to the user.
     func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void) {
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
 //            print("will present: ", notification)
 //            Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(notification.request.content.userInfo)
 //            completionHandler(.alert)
             let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

             // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
              Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

             // Print message ID.
             print(" ")
             print("Notification received : \(notification)")
             print("-- New message from Notification ios10 only --")
             print(" ")

             guard
                 let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
                 let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
                 let body = alert["body"] as? String,
                 let title = alert["title"] as? String
                 else {
                     // handle any error here
                     return
                 }

             print("Title: \(title) \nBody:\(body)")

             let banner = NotificationBanner(title: title, subtitle: body, style: .success)
             banner.show()

             // Change this to your preferred presentation option
             //completionHandler([])
         }
     }

     // BACKGROUND: The method will be called on the delegate when the user responded to the notification by opening the application, dismissing the notification or choosing a UNNotificationAction. The delegate must be set before the application returns from applicationDidFinishLaunching:.
     func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void) {
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             print("didReceive")
             let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
             // Print message ID.
             if let messageID = userInfo["gcmMessageIDKey"] {
               print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
             }
             print(userInfo)
             if let body = userInfo["body"] as? String {
                 print("inbody")
                 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("userInfo"), object: body)
             }
             //Push().handlePush(info: userInfo)
             // Print full message.
             print(userInfo)
             Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
             completionHandler()
         }
     }
 }

 // MARK: - MessagingDelegate methods
 extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {

     func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
         //log.info("FCM registration token received = \(fcmToken)")
         print("FCM registration token received = \(fcmToken)")
         let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
         // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
         // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
     }

     func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
         //log.info("didReceive message = \(remoteMessage)")
         print("didReceive message = \(remoteMessage)")
     }

     func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
         print(" - - - FIR Remote message - - - ")
         print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
         //Push().handlePush(info: remoteMessage.appData)
     }
 }
```

In my Info.plist I have `FirebaseAppdelegateProxyEnable` set to `NO`

In capabilities, I have Push Notifications enabled and Remote Notifications are enabled too in Background Mode.

I'm using Xcode 11.1. I have converted my project to Swift 5 (it was created with Swift 3), I have changed the build system to the new one.

I have two targets with this project I don't know if it can be related to my issue.

I try with an empty new project with the same AppDelegate.swift, same bundle identifier and it works.

Comment: Are you getting Firebase token in **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** ?

Comment: I'm getting Firebase token in didReceiveRegistrationToken in MessagingDelegate

Comment: I think your converted function code is different soo please put your code in my answer function and check it's called or not ?

Comment: Im not sure but shouldEstablishDirectChannel may make Firebase send direct message to your app without passing through the usual Apple push notification service. FYI didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler is still the default way to receive background notification (notification with a content-available= true in the notification payload) when your app has background notification and capabilities enabled

Comment: @NicolasManzini I try to set it to False, but no change. 

I find that didReceiveRemoteNotification was deprecated and will be replaced by willPresent  in Foreground and didReceive in Background.

And the problem is that is works in my new app

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I try but no change

Comment: hi, hopes you are doing well. i had same issue then i found a solution on my on please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955996/push-notifications-are-not-working-when-i-disconnect-my-device-from-xcode/54957289#54957289 this link

Comment: @hussnainahmad thanks but i'm using the same key for apns for both app.

Comment: If I comment `var window: UIWindow?` it works

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // put your code here
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    // put your code here
}
```